# How to launch Play Store in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

Hi i am creating a simple game and i want yo know how to launch Play Store in ligbdx when someone would like to rate my game.

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have two options :

1. Either open directly by using complete URL (generic for all platform)

   ```
   Gdx.net.openURI("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xyz.abc");
   ```
2. Use [interfacing](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) and implement platform specific APIs.

   - eg. like for Android

     ```
     public void rate(){

         Intent rateIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xyz.abc"));
         //or 
         //Intent rateIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+getPackageName()));
         startActivity(rateIntent);
     }
     ```

It prompt a choose dialog, having browser and Playstore app (If PlayStore installed in device) option. choose PlayStore.

**EDIT**

```
try {

   Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName()));
   startActivity(viewIntent);

}catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
    String url="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+getPackageName();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null) {
            startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```